# Getter and setter coming from different interfaces

Tags: c#, interface

I really need to have something like this:

```
interface IReadableVar
{
    object Value { get; }
}

interface IWritableVar
{
    object Value { set; }
}

interface IReadableWritableVar : IReadableVar, IWritableVar
{
}
```

However when I try to use `IReadableWritableVar.Value` I get compile errors unless I explicitly cast to base interface, like here:

```
static void Main()
{
    IReadableWritableVar var = null;
    var t = var.Value;  // <-- CS0229: Ambiguity between 'IReadableVar.Value' and 'IWritableVar.Value'
    var.Value = null;   // <-- CS0229: Ambiguity between 'IReadableVar.Value' and 'IWritableVar.Value'

    var v = ((IReadableVar)var).Value;  // compiles fine
    ((IWritableVar)var).Value = null;   // compiles fine
}
```

Why do I get these errors although everything should be clear to the compiler? Is there any way to fix this problem other than casting (hundreds of places in the application)?

Update: it was suggested this is a dupe of [Implementing 2 Interfaces with 'Same Name' Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532148) but this is slightly different as in the other case there's no inheritance in interfaces. Anyway, the problem is solved now - see accepted answer.

Comment: I think compiler is not designed in that way to distinguish between identical properties in different interfaces based on getter or setter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementing 2 Interfaces with 'Same Name' Properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/532148/implementing-2-interfaces-with-same-name-properties)

Comment: Note that `IWritableVar` is suspect, because write-only properties are suspect. Any caller that can write a property should probably also be able to read it, and where this doesn't make sense, you probably want a method, not a property.

Comment: @JeroenMostert these vars are in reality more complicated and connected to a hardware system, and some of these things can only be written. At the same time they have to be properties to be used by WPF binding system. Complicated to explain without knowing whole system, but this does make sense this way.

Comment: It may be fruitful to add that you want to use the property in WPF to the question text.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A possible workaround can be modify your interface `IReadableWritableVar` like this:

```
interface IReadableWritableVar : IReadableVar, IWritableVar
{
    new object Value { get; set; }
}
```

But keep in my that a valid implementation should be:

```
class ReadableWritableVar : IReadableWritableVar
{
    public object Value
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        set { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    object IWritableVar.Value
    {
        set { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    object IReadableVar.Value
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
}
```

A more concrete example:

```
class ReadableWritableVar : IReadableWritableVar
{
    public object Value
    {
        get { return ((IReadableVar)this).Value; }
        set { ((IWritableVar)this).Value = value; }
    }

    object _val;

    object IWritableVar.Value { set { _val = value; } }

    object IReadableVar.Value => _val;
}
```

Or even better:

```
class ReadableWritableVar : IReadableWritableVar
{
    public object Value { get; set; }

    object IWritableVar.Value { set { Value = value; } }

    object IReadableVar.Value => Value;
}
```

Comment: Just a note: you don't need explicit implementations. `class ReadableWritableVar : IReadableWritableVar
{
    public object Value { get; set; }
}` compiles fine.

Comment: Just adding the `new Value` property to 'IReadableWritableVar' solved the problem for me. The class implementing it was doing non-explicit implemenation. It's a workaround but works great - thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7):

Interesting question. I think extension methods will help in this case.

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static object GetValue(this IReadableVar v)
    {
        return v.Value;
    }

    public static void SetValue(this IWritableVar v, object value)
    {
        v.Value = value;
    }
}
```

You need to change the code to use it:

```
IReadableWritableVar variable = null;
var t = variable.GetValue();
variable.SetValue(null);
```

The extension method does the cast for you.

Comment: This is interesting approach, but in such case I would just use `SetValue` and `GetValue` methods and get rid of property entirely. Unfortunately property is required as it has to work with WPF binding system.

Answer (score 2):

Well, effectively Getter and Setter are just two methods. When we use `IReadableWritableVar` interface there are two methods with identical name inherited from base interfaces and compiler doesn't know which of these two should it use hence the ambiguity.

When we cast that to one of these interfaces the other member's gone and there's no error.

If we *implement* those member there will be no error as compiler will use that implementation:

```
class ReadableWritableVar : IReadableWritableVar
{
    public object Value { get; set; }
}

var @var = new ReadableWritableVar();
var t = @var.Value;
```

Also you can use an explicit interface members implementation from @Alessandro D'Andria's answer if it is required that you use interface and not class.

Comment: These are just methods internally, but I think two different methods. This is why I don't understand why the compiler behaves this way. If I would use two methods (setter and getter) instead of a property the problem wouldn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

using abstract class istead of interface will resolve your problem.

```
public abstract class ReadableWritableVar : IReadableVar, IWritableVar
{
    public object Value { get; set; }       
}
```

Comment: But don't call it `IReadableWritableVar` if it's not an interface, call it either `ReadableWritableVar` or `AbstractReadableWritableVar`.

Comment: Unfortunately this have to be an interface, and the class implementing it implements more of them.

Answer (score 0):

One possible alternative is to use explicit (java style) get and set methods instead of a property:

```
interface IReadableVar
{
    object GetValue();
}

interface IWritableVar
{
    void SetValue(object value);
}

interface IReadableWritableVar : IReadableVar, IWritableVar
{

}
```

The usage then becomes:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IReadableWritableVar aVar = null;

    var t = aVar.GetValue();
    aVar.SetValue(null);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this has to be a property because of WPF Binding system which is going to use this.

Comment: You said this goes to hardware, directly from bindings in WPF?  You need more layers here.

Comment: @BryanBoettcher Well, actually I do have more layers. But still something that can only be written at the hardware level is a writable only property in these layers...